# Find address (cell/row) for COUNTIFS function

Tags: excel, function

I have an Excel file populated with a large amount of COUNTIFS functions (above 300). The formulas work fine but I need to be able to find the address for each COUNTIFS result as the data source is very large.

i.e. if COUNTIFs gives me result of 1 for the selected parameters, I need to be able to know which cell/row the function is counting from the data source.

I was thinking this could be done with the ADDRESS function, but I am not sure how this can be used together with COUNTIFS.

Comment: I think you need to use the match function. If you give more detail you can probably get a specific answer as a formula.

Comment: there is no simple wrapper that one can use on the existing COUNTIFS() to return the address of those that are counted.  But you can use conditional formatting and enter the criteria that matches the criteria in the COUNTIFS to color the cells that are included.  There are some complicated formula that may get close but they will be array type formula and as such, using too many and/or referencing too large a data set will slow down the calc times.

Comment: @ScottCraner - did I misinterpret the question?

Comment: @Jeeped one of us did.  It will take the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a user-defined function.

Using the below code, you would get this result:
[image]

```
Public Function ListAddresses(SearchTerm As Variant, SearchRange As Range) As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet, rCell As Range

    Set WS = Sheets(SearchRange.Parent.Name)
    SearchTerm = UCase(SearchTerm)

    Set SearchRange = Intersect(WS.UsedRange, SearchRange)

    For Each rCell In SearchRange.Cells
        If UCase(rCell.Value) = SearchTerm Then
            ListAddresses = ListAddresses & rCell.Address(False, False) & " | "
        End If

    Next rCell

    If ListAddresses <> "" Then
        ListAddresses = Left(ListAddresses, Len(ListAddresses) - 3)
    Else
        ListAddresses = "<none>"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Do you know if it is possible also to highlight these cells in the raw data? Either having them in a different colour or ideally adding an "X" to their next cells (in D4 and D7 in this case). sorry I'm terrible at VBA.. :(

Comment: Hi - apologies for the late feedback, I did not notice your last comment. I accepted your answer, could you also help on highlighting the cells counted through COUNTIFS in the raw data?

Comment: Thanks @user9990184 user defined functions cannot touch the worksheet (i.e. change the background/font/etc), so if you want to actually update the rest of the sheet you would need a macro. It would probably be easier to use conditional formatting. In my specific example, select C4 to C7 and set the conditional format to `=$A$1=C4`. I hope that helps you. If not, post another question, I'll give it a tick if it's sensible and try to answer it. Welcome to SO. ️‍‍️⛱️

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(C$3:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C:C)))/(C$3:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))=1), ROW(1:1)), COLUMN(B:B), 4, 1, "Shett4")
```

[image]

Comment: I took the whole `i.e.` statement to mean that the `1` is the fact that it is being counted, matches all criteria, not that the whole COUNTIFS() returns 1, but your interpretation may be correct and OP wants to count the literal `1` from the return of the COUNTIFS().  I am second guessing my initial interpretation.

Comment: Hey @jeeped, in case you didn't notice, the OP accepted my answer over yours. This marks the first time in the earth's history that this has happened. I just wanted to make sure you didn't overlook this colossal moment. It may not happen again... 

Comment: @PGCodeRider, Momentous occasion indeed, Congratulations! (and good luck with the highlighting)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your criteria rows are aligned, you can find the rows that are going into the count. Referencing the image below, enter this as an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in an area with the same number of rows that the `COUNTIFS` returned (I entered the formula into `H2:H4` in the image):

```
=SMALL(IF(((A2:A11=F1)+(B2:B11=F2)+(C2:C11=F3))=3,ROW(A2:A11)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&F4)))
```

[image]