# Show addresses of cell value matches in two compared ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Excel worksheets with numerical ids in.  I wish to compare list one against list two and where matches are found return the respective cell addresses for each match.

[image]

I am able via VBA to look through each list and return the address of the match in the small list but not of the match found in the larger list.
Any help would be appreciated.  I guess the reality is that the message of the address it currently displays is simply the next cell in the loop.

```
Sub FindMatchAddress()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsInp As Worksheet
Dim wsRD As Worksheet
Dim rngInp As Range
Dim rngRD As Range

Set wsInp = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set wsRD = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set rngInp = wsInp.Range("B2:B11")

  For Each cell In rngInp
    If IsError(Application.Match(cell, rngRD, 0)) Then
    Else
        MsgBox cell.Address
        cell.Offset(, 12) = "Found"
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: I believe I just answered this with a formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51028036/find-address-cell-row-for-countifs-function/51028264#51028264).

Comment: `rngRD` is never set so it is nothing.

Comment: Will a formula not work? =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B:B,0)),"Not Found",ADDRESS(MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B:B,0),2)) Edit: This only accurate if the value/ID is not repeated on Sheet 2.

Comment: Thank you, the value/ID is repeated on Sheet2, apologies everyone if I wasn't clear about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `Range.Find`? And also setting `rngRd` as pointed out in the comments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindMatchAddress()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsInp As Worksheet
    Dim wsRD As Worksheet
    Dim rngInp As Range
    Dim rngRD As Range
    Dim rng As Range, tmpRng As Range

    Set wsInp = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsRD = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngInp = wsInp.Range("B2:B11")
    Set rngRD = wsInp.Range("D2:D16")

    For Each rng In rngInp
        Set tmpRng = rngRD.Find(What:=rng.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not tmpRng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox tmpRng.Address
            rng.Offset(, 12) = "Found"
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Phil, reading into your question, I'm taking for granted that the "numerical ids" are in the same column but on different worksheets. If I'm correct then, the below code should work as is. The code finds matching values in worksheet2 and instead of just placing just "Found" in worksheet1, "column N", I add worksheet2's name and the cell address. if your "numerical ids" are in different columns, please change the ws2 column letter to suit you. I've tested it on mock data and it works fine. I've tried to keep it as simple as I could.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim lRow1 As Long
    lRow1 = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim lRow2 As Long
    lRow2 = ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow1
    For j = 2 To lRow2
        If ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = ws2.Range("B" & j).Value Then
            ws1.Range("B" & i).Offset(, 12).Value = "Found: " & ws2.Name & "." & ws2.Range("B" & j).address
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Yes, correct the numerical ids are contained in whole on sheet2 and some will be on Sheet1, Apologies that I wasn't clear about this. I'm not overly concerned about entering "Found" on either sheet, but what is important to me is that I know where the current id is located on sheet one and if it has a match on sheet2 where that is.  My intention is to paste data from sheet1 onto sheet2 where a match is found and overwrite some of the sheet2 content, hence requiring a cell address that i can use offsets to work from.

Comment: This can be easily modified to meet your needs, by using `Offset` and `Resize`, as needed, you can select the range on sheet1 that you want to move to sheet 2. The line of code between the `If_End If` can be changed to either a `ws1.Range("B" & i).Offset(#, #).Resize(#, #).Copy` and then Pasted to Sheet2.